# Truncate selected value in SwiftUI Picker with limited width

Tags: swiftui, picker

I'm implementing a Picker in SwiftUI. The picker values are strings that vary in size, but the picker itself has a maxWidth due to UI limitations. Some of the strings won't fit, and that's fine with me. However, at the moment, the string is wrapped, increasing the height of the picker, like so:

[image]

I'd like to limit the string to just one line, truncating the string, and keeping the picker height the same.

I've tried

```
.frame(maxHeight: 20)
.clipped()
.contentShape(Rectangle())
```

on the picker, but that gives me this:

[image]

I'd like to truncate the string. How can I do this? NOTE: it should only truncate here, not in the dropdown list.

I've played around with `.lineLimit(1)`, `.multilineTextAlignment(.leading)`, `.truncationMode(.tail)`, on both the text in the ForEach block, and on the picker itself, but no luck so far.

Here is the full code that I have now:

```
Picker("Theme", selection: $selectedThemeRawValue) {
    ForEach(Theme.allCases.map({$0.rawValue}), id: \.self) { value in
        Text(value)
            .lineLimit(1)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
            .truncationMode(.tail)
    }
}
.accentColor(.primary)
.frame(maxHeight: 20)
.clipped()
.contentShape(Rectangle())
.lineLimit(1)
.multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
.truncationMode(.tail)
```

Does anyone have an idea on how I can do this?

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I would like to do the same thing

Comment: I did not find a solution for this, unfortunately. Ultimately, I changed my UI to allow more space for the (unexpanded) picker. I set maxWidth to .infinity, and now the (unexpanded) picker width automatically adapts to show the entire selected string.

Comment: Thanks, I will probably implement a similar solution. I will just provide shorter values for the picker (they were definitely too long).